# How to create a table that displays the word and amount of times it was found in a specific column

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R and I have been assigned to analyze an information out of a specific column inside a xlsx file. I have been trying for days and researching how I can do the analysis but I can't seem to figure it out. This could be because of my lack of knowledge in R.

The values inside the column to be analyzed are the types of SUDs the person had/have at the moment of question. The values looks something like this....

Header -> Axis I

Row 1 -> PTSD, Alcohol Abuse, Cocaine Abuse, Intoxication

Row 2 -> Tabacco Abuse, Alcohol Abuse, PTSD

Row 3 -> Opioid Abuse, Opioid Intoxication, Cocaine Abuse

The idea is to create x2 types of analysis and save it in an excel table.
First analysis is to know the amount of people who had/have PTSD, Alcohol Abuse, etc...
Second Analysis is the same as the First but having more than 1 substance use. (PTSD, Alcohol Abuse, Cocaine Abuse, etc...)

The closes I have been able to get is with the following code:

```
SUB_DATA <- read.csv("SUD_FILE.csv")
table(unlist(strsplit(SUB_DATA$Dx.Axis.I, "[,]")))
```

With this code I get the following result [see attached img]
[Results from running the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emWJY.png)

As seen in the img, the code does the 1st analysis I want to do but, for some reason I do not understand, it seperates the values into x2 variables with the same name. If I add both values presented in the output, I actually get the correct amount for the poeple with Alcohol Abuse (n=19).

I still do now even know how to make the second question.

Any help would be appreciated. If I manage to solve this, I will update the post.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1 -> I tried to put the column to be more clearer. I have also added an img at the bottom for the column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t30Go.png)

PS: The code displayed is the only code I have that does what I want. I can attached an excel file with the same portion if it helps.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You may want to try posting a small sample of the data you have and the kind of output you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because of additional whitespaces in one of the words. In `strsplit` split the words with comma and any whitespace if present. You may also use `trimws` to trim the whitespaces.

```
result <- table(trimws(unlist(strsplit(SUB_DATA$Dx.Axis.I, ",\\s*"))))
```